# Laravel 4 Hide Auth Basic prompt Dialogue on guest user

Tags: authentication, laravel-4

As i implement auth.basic to certain route on my Laravel 4 installation, if i'm not logged in a prompt message box appear to enter my username and password as i am entering restricted page, however i just want it to return 401 error not the prompt box.

As i am using ember at my front end if i request restricted unauthorized page from it, the laravel displays prompt which pretty much messed up the experience of my app.

I just want it to return 401 error and from front end side i will manage redirect to route of the ember app, as per the response code. How should i do it? This is what i did on laravel side:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth.basic'), function(){
       Route::resource('profiles', 'ProfilesController');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I Disabled it at Guard.php under Illuminate/Auth